# Destroying client-related data in a multi-client/server system

Tags: c++, tcp

I will build a multi-client/server system. It's expected to work like this:

1. The client comunicates with the server using TCP/IP
2. When the client makes the connection to the server, the client sends a command string. When the server receives the command string, it parses it, do the required work and then sends a response to the client.
3. When the client closes the TCP connection, the server will destroy the resource related to this client.
4. The server is a multi-threaded program. The command `receive`, the command `parse`, the command `deal` and the response to the client may each be in a different thread.

Now, I want to define a `CmdTcpContext` class to contain the data related to the client.

```
class CmdTcpContext
 18 {
 19 public:
 20     CmdTcpContext(){recv_buff_.SetRecvList(&recv_list_);}
 21     ~CmdTcpContext(){}
 22     
 23     CmdRecvBuffer & recv_buff(){return recv_buff_;}
 24     SendBuffer & send_buff(){return send_buff_;}
 25 
 26     RecvList<CmdPackage> & recv_list(){return recv_list_;}
 27     RecvList<CmdPackage> & send_list(){return send_list_;}
 28     
 29     InetAddr & inet_addr(){return addr_;}
 30     SockStream & sock_stream(){return stream_;}
 31 
 32     EventHandler * event_handler(){return handler_;}
 33     void event_handler(EventHandler * eh){handler_ = eh;}
 34 private:
 35     SockStream stream_;
 36     InetAddr addr_;
 37 
 38     CmdRecvBuffer recv_buff_;
 39     SendBuffer send_buff_;
 40 
 41     RecvList<CmdPackage> recv_list_;
 42     RecvList<CmdPackage> send_list_;
 43 
 44     EventHandler *handler_;
 45 };
```

My problem is: how can I destroy the `CmdTcpContext` object when the client closes the connection?

Comment: How about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)? Just remove from the vector when the connection is closed.

Comment: Is the question about how to _know when_ to destroy the object, or really about how to destroy it?

Comment: @jogojapan, Because it is a multi-thread programe, the CmdTcpContext may been accessed by different thread,how to know when to destroy the object?

Comment: @bbg I see. Couldn't you have one `CmdTcpContext` object for every client, i.e. create a new `CmdTcpContext` object when a client connects to the server, and pass that object to the thread that performs the processing for that client? When the thread is done, it can destroy the object, knowing that for any new client, a new object will be created.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg,When the server receives the connection is closed in one thread, but the CmdTcpContext object may been accessed by other thread.if i delete the CmdTcpContext object at this time,the programe may be crashed.

Comment: @jogojapan I have one CmdTcpContext object for every client,but the recv and send in different thread, and all these thread is in the thread pool.

Comment: @bbg But you pass data between these threads. Can't you pass the `CmdTcpContext` object along? (Or a pointer to it?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23474/discussion-between-bbg-and-jogojapan)

Comment: You may want to look up [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), and of course the mutex and lock functions and classes of the [C++ thread support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).